# SVN-repo out of sync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, synchronization

TLDR; My version of the SVN-repo differs from my teamates. Even though the repo-UUID is identical and we are using the same branch (exactly the same repo-links).

My SVN was working fine before i went home for vacation.

I came back, updated my repo, commit some changes. Everything seemed to work fine. But it turns out that my team cannot see my commits and when updating - my commit seems to be the latest one. Looking through their clients, the revision-numbers i have checked in collide with other commits.

Im using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - 
svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)

I tried removing the repository and checking it out (removing the .svn dir as well) - and when i do, my latest commit is HEAD. (Instead of the real HEAD which has a revision number way higher).

When i browse the repo from the web-browser, my commit is HEAD.
When they browse the very same link - their commit is HEAD.

Restarting computer does nothing. Reinstalling subversion (removing ~/.subversion) did nothing.

We tried checking out the repo using different user - still my commit is HEAD.
If i use my account on different machine, it works fine.
The repo-UUID is the same for me and my colleagues.

Im thinking this might be some kind of cache issue, but what cache is both used for svn and browser?

**Additional thoughts:**
I am also using a VPN to access the corporate network. Could there be a cache there? But the SVN-traffic is using TLS, what could possibly cache TLS-data?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but aren't you using a different address for your local repo, or maybe you are using some virtual hostnames ?  try to ping the server via the name it is used in your SVN, and see if it is the server you have SVN on, i mean they have the same IP.

Comment: Not at all a silly question. All help is appreciated. The URL we use are identical. Pinging the hostname of the SVN-server did not result in the same IP! Contacted our CM-center and it turns out they relocated the repo (but apparently kept the old one as well for whatever reason). Flushing my DNS-cache fixed the problem! Thanks @Simion!

Answer (score 1):

@Simion pointed out that it might be a good idea to make sure the hostname of the Repo resolves in the same IP.

Turns out that was the problem. The CM-Center had moved the repo to another server (and for unknown reasons kept a copy of the repo on the old server - which caused all this confusion) and the Infra department had changed the IP of the repo hostname.

**Flusing my local DNS-cache fixed the problem!**